# How to integrate a web3 browser in my crypto wallet expo app

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ethers.js, walletconnect, browsers

I have created a crypto wallet using Expo and now want to integrate a web3 browser like they have in metamask or trustwallet. i don't know how to start, any guidance or article or help will be highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the similar thing, I am starting with the following https://github.com/abcoathup/expo-web3. I have not made it work yet, but hope the information helps